# How to use Sass variables for view-specific stylesheets in Ruby on Rails without error?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

In Ruby Rails 7, I am trying to create a sass stylesheet for a specific view. I want the stylesheet to use a variable defined in another stylesheet. However I get an error when I try to reference the variable. My files are:

**colors.css.scss:**

```
 $my-background-color: blue;
```

**myPage.css.scss:**

```
html{
    background-color: $my-background-color;
}
```

**application.css.scss:**

```
 /*
 *= require_self
 */


@import "colors.css.scss";
@import "landing.css.scss";
```

**config/initializers/assets.rb:**

```
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( colors.css.scss)
 Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( myPage.css.scss)
```

**views/myPage.html.erb:**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "myPage" %>

<h1>Some Title</h1>
<p>Some description</p>
```

**ERROR:**
**`SassC::SyntaxError in myController#myPage`**

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "html": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
        on line 3:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/myPage.css.scss
>> html{
```

then error highlights  `stylesheet_link_tag` in the myPage.html.erb file. Removing the stylesheet link tag works, but of course, this applies the style to all views. I only want it applied to myPage.

sassc-rails is installed